# Execute Example Code in Matlab when Publishing a Function

Tags: matlab, syntax, publish, comments

**Background**
Matlab has a publish function which outputs a, say, .html file based on the syntax of the comments. Sections which contain example code are indicated by a '%' followed by three spaces. An example function can be seen below, and the .html file generated by the publish function can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yUez.png).

```
function randomImage = GenerateRandomImage(n)
%% TestFunction
% generates a random image
% 
% randomImage = GenerateRandomImage(n) returns an nxn array of random pixels
% 
%% Example
%   randomImage = GenerateRandomImage(10);
%   figure; imagesc(abs(randomImage));

randomImage = rand(n);
end
```

Matlab will not automatically evaluate the example code, unless I create a separate script with the example code explicitly uncommitted. An example script is seen below. This time, it automatically includes the outputs of that script, such as the image produced by the example script shown here [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s0rf.png).

```
%% TestFunction
% generates a random image
% 
% randomImage = GenerateRandomImage(n) returns an nxn array of random pixels
% 
%% Example
  randomImage = GenerateRandomImage(10);
  figure; imagesc(abs(randomImage));
```

**The Question**
Is it possible for the publish function to automatically evaluate the code snippits in the comments of a function and include those outputs in the html file?

Comment: There's nothing explicit in the publishing documentation, which is expected TBH. This would be a nightmare to try and code robustly.

Comment: I think you are unfortunately correct. It seems the only alternative is to create a separate script.

Comment: For anyone who would find it useful, the documentation for commenting a code and publishing it can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matlab publisher is explicitly meant to be performed on **scripts**, not function files, since its purpose is to produce a report, where individual *sections* (marked with `%%`) become headings, and lines beginning with `%` *immediately* under the `%%` become the *description* text for that section. Anything that follows *after* that, both code and comment lines, will be presented by the publisher in a nice little box as the code that was run for that section, and then the results of that code will be shown below that box, but contained within their section.

Putting code in the *description* text for that section, expecting it to be run is counter-intuitive. In fact, the only reason you might want to put a code snippet in the description is if you wanted to mention some code *without* running it.
For this reason the publisher provides special syntax (indent by 2 spaces for monotyped text, 3 spaces to add syntax-highlighting to your code).

Publisher is a nice tool, but unfortunately it's fairly limited. The main limitation for me is that you cannot choose which code sections to show results for and which ones not to; it's all or nothing. Therefore I usually resort to a "latex + saved matlab figures + makefile" approach instead for flexible reports. But publisher is nice if you want something quick and dirty; e.g. it's good for keeping a logbook / diary of your work.

Anyway, to answer your question, no, you can't put code in the *description* and expect it to run. Nor are you expected to 'publish' functions; the fact that a function file responds at all to publishing in the first place is probably more of a side-effect of how publisher gets called more than anything.

Comment: Sorry, I just got what you were asking exactly, basically you want to create html pages for your functions as documentation, and you'd like the "Examples" to be run at the end of the html page. The answer is no, that's not what publisher is for, publisher is specifically for scripts, so it does not provide such functionality.